# Polymorphic Relation - Can not store all files at database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to do store post images at database and I'm using dropzonejs. I'ma able to store images at storage, I mean images successfully move storage folder. But when I store at database, weird problem happening.. Laravel insert just some of images at database ?

For example, I had uploaded 10 images, all files moved storage folder but in database only three records show up ? or sometimes two or four..

How do I fix this ?

**Dropzone configuration**

```
Dropzone.options.mDropzoneTwo = {
        paramName: "images",
        maxFiles: 10,
        maxFilesize: 2, // MB
        url: '../../media/store',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token,
        },
        uploadMultiple: true,

        accept: function (file, done) {
            done();
        },

        init: function() {
            this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
                formData.append("post_type", post.dataset.type);
                formData.append("post_id", post.dataset.id);
            });
        },

        success: function () {
            console.log(this.files[0].xhr.responseText)
        }
    };
```

**AdminController**

```
public function storePostMedia(Request $request)
{
    // trying to get model by post type, there are several models depending by post types
    $table = $request->get("post_type");
    $model = getModel($table);
    // finding post
    $post = $model->find($request->get("post_id"));
    $media = new Media;
    // store images
    foreach ($request->file("images") as $image){
        $new_media = $media->storePostImages($image);
        $post->media()->save($new_media);
    }
}
```

**storePostImages() method**

```
public function storePostImages($file)
{
    // get image - rename - storage to storage folder
    $realName = str_slug(pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME));
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $new_name = str_slug($realName) . "-" . time() . "." . $extension;
    $fullPath = \Storage::putFileAs("posts", $file, $new_name);
    // save to database
    $this->name = $new_name;
    $this->path = $fullPath;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Just guessing, could it be the time function is getting hit more than once per second, so it doesn't change between new file names?  `$new_name = str_slug($realName) . "-" . time() . "." . $extension;`

Comment: @ourmandave uploaded files have different names, time addition might be same but definitely files have different names at the end

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with creating new model instance for each record

```
foreach ($request->file("images") as $image){ 
    $media = new Media;
    $new_media = $media->storePostImages($image);
    $post->media()->save($new_media);
}
```